# Error while importing modules in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express, routes, node-modules

I am trying to import some modules in an ExpressJS app but it throws the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './public/js/date.js'
>   ....*more error logs*...
>   at Object. (/home/user007/todoApp_SSRendered/routes/route-add.js:2:23)

I have some deeply nested folders with modules all scattered over places. My folder structure is something like this. I think it has something to do with how I am specifying routes for the modules.

[image]

My **app.js** import the module **route-main.js** located in **routes** folder

`const mainRoute = require('./routes/route-main.js')`
`app.use('/', mainRoute)`

The **route-main.js** on the other hand imports all the other modules inside the same routes folder

`const addTask = require('./routes/route-add.js')`
+ .....*other three remaining files*...
`let taskToUpdate = require('./public/db/tasks.json')`

Going a level more deep, all the other 4 files inside routes folder (except route-main.js), require the two files in js folder

`const newDateFormat = require('./public/js/date.js')`
`const writeFile = require('./public/js/writeFile.js')`

So overall the module dependency link (require) is something like:

**app.js** --> **main.js** --> **(route-add, route-delete...)** --> **(date, writeFile)**

**Note**: In **app.js**, I only require **main.js** and so on for the others (there is no double require for the same module). I'm using Express 4.14.1 and have Pug and body-parser as the remaining dependencies.
Also the app is fully server-side rendered if it helps.

**THANK YOU :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relative path issue, since `route-main.js` and `/public` are not in the same folder, you need to replace:

```
let taskToUpdate = require('./public/db/tasks.json')
```

with

```
let taskToUpdate = require('../public/db/tasks.json')
```

And check that when you're requiring files from other folders that the relative path is correct.

Comment: oh ok. so if i am requiring anything from a different folder 1 level outside, I need to use **../fullPathName**  right ? I have also seen somewhere that when you import modules from the same folder you can just do **/moduleName**. I am so confused with routing path using / . Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Yes, ./ is from the same folder and ../ is for 1 level outside. If you're using webpack and you want to avoid that, the resolve functionality can help you out:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/